# creating node in neo4j taking time through java driver

Tags: neo4j

I am creating nodes in **Neo4j** using `neo4j-java driver` with the help of following Cipher Query.

```
String cipherQuery = "CREATE (n:MLObsTemp { personId: " + personId + ",conceptId: " + conceptId
                            + ",obsId: " + obsId + ",MLObsId: " + mlObsId + ",encounterId: " + encounterId + "}) RETURN n";
```

Function for creating query

```
createNeo4JObsNode(String cipherQuery);
```

Implementation of the Function

```
private void createNeo4JObsNode(String cipherQuery) throws Exception {
   try (ConNeo4j greeter = new ConNeo4j("bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "qwas")) {
   System.out.println("Executing query : " + cipherQuery);

  try (Session session = driver.session()) {
   StatementResult result = session.run(cipherQuery);

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Error" + e.getMessage());
  }

 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}
```

Making relation for the above nodes using below code

```
String obsMatchQuery = "MATCH (m:MLObsTemp),(o:Obs) WHERE m.obsId=o.obsId CREATE (m)-[:OBS]->(o)";
        createNeo4JObsNode(obsMatchQuery);
        
        String personMatchQuery = "MATCH (m:MLObsTemp),(p:Person) WHERE m.personId=p.personId CREATE (m)-[:PERSON]->(p)";
        createNeo4JObsNode(personMatchQuery);
        
        String encounterMatchQuery = "MATCH (m:MLObsTemp),(e:Encounter) WHERE m.encounterId=e.encounterId CREATE (m)-[:ENCOUNTER]->(e)";
        createNeo4JObsNode(encounterMatchQuery);
        
        String conceptMatchQuery = "MATCH (m:MLObsTemp),(c:Concept) WHERE m.conceptId=c.conceptId CREATE (m)-[:CONCEPT]->(c)";
        createNeo4JObsNode(conceptMatchQuery);
```

It is taking me 13 seconds on average for creating nodes and 12 seconds for making relations. I have 350k records in my database for which I have to create nodes and their respective relations.

How can I improve my code? Moreover, is this the best way for creating nodes in Neo4j using bolt server and neo4j-java driver?

## EDIT

I am now using the **query parameter** in my code

```
 HashMap<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
         ((HashMap<String, Object>) parameters).put("personId", 1390);
         ((HashMap<String, Object>) parameters).put("obsId", 14001);
         ((HashMap<String, Object>) parameters).put("conceptId", 5978);
         ((HashMap<String, Object>) parameters).put("encounterId", 10810);
         ((HashMap<String, Object>) parameters).put("mlobsId", 2);
         
         
         
         String cypherQuery=
                 "CREATE (m:MLObsTemp { personId: $personId, ObsId: $obsId, conceptId: $conceptId, MLObsId: $mlobsId, encounterId: $encounterId}) "
                + "WITH m MATCH (p:Person { personId: $personId }) CREATE (m)-[:PERSON]->(p) "
                + "WITH m MATCH (e:Encounter {encounterId: $encounterId }) CREATE (m)-[:Encounter]->(e) "
                + "WITH m MATCH (o:Obs {obsId: $obsId }) CREATE (m)-[:OBS]->(o) "
                + "WITH m MATCH (c:Concept {conceptId: $conceptId }) CREATE (m)-[:CONCEPT]->(c) "
                + " RETURN m";
```

Creating Node function

```
 try {
  ConNeo4j greeter = new ConNeo4j("bolt://localhost:7687", "neo4j", "qwas");

  try {
   Session session = driver.session();
   StatementResult result = session.run(cypherQuery, parameters);
   System.out.println(result);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("[WARNING] Null Row");
  }

 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I am also performing the indexing in order to speed up the process

```
  CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (P:Person) ASSERT P.personId IS UNIQUE
        CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (E:Encounter) ASSERT E.encounterId IS UNIQUE
        CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (O:Obs) ASSERT O.obsId IS UNIQUE
        CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (C:Concept) ASSERT C.conceptId IS UNIQUE
```

Here is the plan for 1 cypher [query-profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY0N6.png)

Now the performance has improved but not significant. I am using neo4j-java-driver version 1.6.1. How can I **batch** my cipher queries to improve the performance further.

Comment: Do you have indexes created on the relevant id properties? Have you profiled your queries and inspected your query plans? Also, consider parameterizing your queries rather than using string appending.

Comment: How can I inspect my query plan and parameterised my queries. Could you elaborate it further provide some links.?

Comment: Here's the link for [query profiling](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/), and here's the one for [parameterizing your queries](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/).

Comment: You should use parameters and indexes/constraints and also batch your updates, see: https://medium.com/neo4j/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher-73c7f693c8cc

Comment: The query language is named *Cypher*, not *Cipher*, please use the proper name.

Comment: Updated tip section of my answer with information about using transactions for batch processing.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to minimize redundant work in your cyphers.

MLObsTemp has a lot of redundant properties, and you are searching for it to create every link. Relationships defeat the need to create properties for foreign keys (node ids)

I would recommend a Cypher that does everything together, and uses parameters like this...

```
CREATE (m:MLObsTemp) 
WITH m MATCH (p:Person {id:"$person_id"}) CREATE (m)-[:PERSON]->(p)
WITH m MATCH (e:Encounter {id:"$encounter_id"}) CREATE (m)-[:Encounter]->(e)
WITH m MATCH (c:Concept {id:"$concept_id"}) CREATE (m)-[:CONCEPT]->(c)
// SNIP more MATCH/CREATE
RETURN m
```

This way, Neo4j doesn't have to find m repeatedly for every relationship. You don't need the ID properties, because that is effectively what the relationship you just created is. Neo4j is very efficient at walking edges (relationships), so just follow the relationship if you need the id value.

TIPS: (mileage may very across Neo4j versions)

- Inline is almost always more efficent than WHERE (`MATCH (n{id:"rawr"})` vs `MATCH (n) WHERE n.id="rawr"`)
- [Parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/) make frequent, similar queries more efficient, as Neo4j will cache how to do it quickly (the `$thing_id` syntax used in the above query.) Also, It protects you from Cypher injection (See [SQL injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp))
- From a Session, you can create a Transaction (Session.run() actually creates a transaction for each run call). You can batch multiple Cyphers using a single transaction (Even using the results of previous Cyphers from the same transaction), because transactions live in memory until you mark it a success and close it. Note that if you are not careful, your transaction can fail with "outofmemory". So remember to commit periodically/between batches. (commit batches of 10k records seems to be the norm when ingesting large data sets)

Comment: Just to note, inline properties vs WHERE should be equivalent, it's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: @InverseFalcon It may depend on your Cypher version, but my experience from profiles is that inline always outperforms WHERE. For complex Cyphers at least, inline seems to be much friendlier to the cypher planner. I don't have the data to back that up though. But it also makes the cypher easier to read in my opinion (as long as you are careful when using create unique)